# Data rows were repeated 4 times when I ( select first 1000 rows) In sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

I use SQL Server 2014 to create a database and a table and inserted 10 rows of data.

The problem that when I select to 1000 rows, rows was repeated 4 times so they are now 40 rows as you can see in the images

[image: first 10 rows]

[image: Last 10 rows]

Now I want to ask: why did this happen?

And how to solve that?

And also I want to ask how to find the query that I entered the data in .. I tried `script table as > CREATE TO > create new query` but it only gives me the table and values

Comment: please share the full query

Comment: How did you enter your 10 rows? Did you run it multiple times by accident?

Comment: ok I as I wrote in question I want to know how to find the full query in the program ? I enserted data once then I dont know where the query gone ~~ can u help ?

Comment: shree.part18 ~~ yeah maybe I did

Comment: @AishaAhmedAhmed Follow this procedure to generate insert statement what you'd used and see whether you ran it 4 times. http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/24277/sql-server-generate-insert-statement-script/

Comment: Those rows aren't identical. Sure, the `w_type` column has duplicates, but the other columns all seem to contain unique information.

Comment: +mr_ec;air ~~ yeah I ran it 4 times .. then how to solve ?I tried to deleete bet it refused

Comment: +damien_The_Unbeleiver no all columns are duplicated

Comment: What's error on deletion

Comment: Pranv Singh  Here is a picture of the error .. sorry i cant add a picture in the comment https://twitter.com/MetfalaDoamz/status/462127276448960513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How** did you try and delete the rows? Did you write a `DELETE` statement and specify an id? Given you have 4 sets of rows that you say are unique (I'll take your word for it) and you have an ID column which repeats, you could adapt the following statement to help you.

```
DELETE TOP (3) FROM dbo.waqf WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

## EDIT

I made a mistake: Using the `TOP (n)` with an `IN` clause won't work as you might think - I should have tested it a bit. That will simply delete the first n rows in the table where the ID is in the specified range. Really you should loop through each of your unique IDs and issue a `DELETE` per id. There's probably a better way of doing this but it's early here and my brain isn't working yet.

```
DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 1
WHILE @id <= (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.waqf)
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (3) FROM dbo.waqf WHERE ID = @id

    SET @id += 1
END
```

Comment: DELETE TOP (30) FROM dbo.waqf WHERE w_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: ok I only haveone question .. how to find my query that i used to insert data ?

Comment: you can't. If you didn't save it then it's gone.

Comment: I saved it yes .. but when I want to edit a row .. ok do u mean every edit I must create a new query?

Comment: Incidentally that TOP `(30)` won't work as you might expect. I made a mistake - you really need to loop through your ID's and do one at a time i.e. `DELETE TOP (3) FROM dbo.waqf WHERE ID = 1` `DELETE TOP (3) FROM dbo.waqf WHERE ID = 2` etc to guarantee that you end up with one of each ID.

Comment: Yes, when you want to edit data you need an `UPDATE` statement. An `UPDATE` is basically a `DELETE` followed by an `INSERT` and you could do that too, but it's much easier to write an `UPDATE` statement like so: `UPDATE dbo.waqf SET w_shape = 'triangle' WHERE m_ID = 1`